# Storing Mat descriptor into database

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing an image processing app on Android which uses the **SURF feature descriptor** in OpenCV for Android.

I performed the image feature detection on my image and wanted to store the detected feature in database. Does anyone has any idea how to store the Mat image with the descriptor into a  database in which I can retrieve it to process?

Because getting the feature from each image and compare the take a lot of processing time and if there is a way to store the obtain feature in somewhere in android then I can speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is serializing your object into a bytestream before storing it. Here is a good tutorial for Android serialization - [Android Serialization Tutorial](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_Serialization_Example_%28Java%29)